# only one char being read in as input in lexer

Tags: rust

So I'm making a lexer in Rust that has a bunch of test cases to pass. The issue with my Rust code right now is that when I'm running a test case with strings, none of the test cases for strings work. but test cases for other tokens are working.

so for example if there was a test that used "hello world":
ie:

```
fn test_03() {
  assert_eq!(lex("hello world"),vec![Token::Alpha(b'h'), Token::Alpha(b'e'), Token::Alpha(b'l'), Token::Alpha(b'l'), Token::Alpha(b'o'), Token::WhiteSpace, Token::Alpha(b'w'), Token::Alpha(b'o'), Token::Alpha(b'r'), Token::Alpha(b'l'), Token::Alpha(b'd'), Token::EOF]);
}
```

the test is failing with this error:

"thread 'test_03' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
left: `[Alpha(111), WhiteSpace, Alpha(100), EOF]`,
right: `[Alpha(104), Alpha(101), Alpha(108), Alpha(108), Alpha(111), WhiteSpace, Alpha(119), Alpha(111), Alpha(114), Alpha(108), Alpha(100), EOF]`', tests/lex.rs:15:3"

WHERE the 'right' has the right values and the left is what my code is producing. So basically it's taking in 'h' but then instead of reading in 'e' next, it's going straight to whitespace.

I've tried debugging small segments with print statements but nothing I've tried has worked. I even tried moving the String handling case to the top but that's not working. Any help on what I can modify would be appreciated as I'm new to Rust and not too sure what could be wrong here!

here is my code:

```
pub enum Token {
  Keyword(Vec<u8>),
  Alpha(u8),
  Digit(u8),
  LeftParen,
  RightParen,
  LeftCurly,
  RightCurly,
  Equal,
  Plus,
  Dash,
  Quote,
  WhiteSpace,
  Semicolon,
  Comma,
  Other,
  EOF,
}

//LEX FUNCTION: 
pub fn lex(input: &str) -> Vec<Token> {
  let bytes = input.as_bytes();
  let mut tokens = vec![];
  let mut count = 0;
  while count < bytes.len() {
      let token = match bytes[count] {
          //handling string input-- not working? 
          0x22 => {
            let mut string = String::new(); // use String instead of Vec<u8>
            count += 1;
            while count < bytes.len() && bytes[count] != 0x22 {
                string.push(bytes[count] as char); // append the character to the string
                count += 1;
            }
            count += 1;
            Token::Keyword(string.into_bytes()) // convert the String back to Vec<u8>
        }
          0x41..=0x5A | 0x61..=0x7A => {
              let mut keyword = vec![bytes[count]];
              while count + 1 < bytes.len()
                  && (bytes[count + 1] >= 0x41 && bytes[count + 1] <= 0x5A
                      || bytes[count + 1] >= 0x61 && bytes[count + 1] <= 0x7A)
              {
                  keyword.push(bytes[count + 1]);
                  count += 1;
              }
              match &keyword[..] {
                  b"true" => Token::Keyword(keyword),
                  b"false" => Token::Keyword(keyword),
                  b"fn" => Token::Keyword(keyword),
                  b"return" => Token::Keyword(keyword),
                  b"let" => Token::Keyword(keyword),
                  _ => Token::Alpha(bytes[count]),
              }
          }
          0x30..=0x39 => Token::Digit(bytes[count]),
          0x28 => Token::LeftParen,
          0x29 => Token::RightParen,
          0x7B => Token::LeftCurly,
          0x7D => Token::RightCurly,
          0x3D => Token::Equal,
          0x2B => Token::Plus,
          0x2D => Token::Dash,
          0x20 | 0xA | 0x9 => Token::WhiteSpace, //whitespace error? 
          0x3B => Token::Semicolon,
          0x2C => Token::Comma,
          _ => Token::Other,
      };
      tokens.push(token);
      count += 1;
  }
  tokens.push(Token::EOF);
  tokens
}


pub fn strip_whitespace(tokens: Vec<Token>) -> Vec<Token> {
  let mut new:Vec<Token> = vec![];
  for token in tokens{
    if token != Token::WhiteSpace{
      new.push(token);
    }
  }
  return new;   
}
```

Comment: Not sure what `cargo` has to do with this, tag removed.

Comment: You could use `Alpha(char)` to make your life *way* easier when debugging, assuming you haven't memorized the ASCII table.

Comment: Tip: Instead of referencing `bytes[count]` all over the place, use a capture, like `s @ 0x22` or `a @ 0x41..=0x5A` which means you have a handy variable `s` or `a` respectively to use.

Comment: Is that some kind of lookahead parser in there? I'm not sure that approach will work, but I believe the problem is you're shooting yourself in the foot: You're manipulating `count` when looking ahead, which means `bytes[count]` shifts. It will not be `h` any longer, your `while` loop will mess with it.

Comment: When writing a parser like this you'll often want to have a state machine involved, not just a simple character iterator. In Rust it's easy to map states using an `enum` and then `match (state, c)` where `c` is the character being inspected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your code is doing:

`bytes[count]` is `h`.

```rs
let token = match bytes[count] {
```

This is between `a` and `z` so it takes the second branch.

```rs
0x41..=0x5A | 0x61..=0x7A => {
```

`keyword` has the first 5 bytes pushed to it.

```rs
keyword.push(bytes[count + 1]);
```

`bytes[count + 1]` is now a space, so the second condition is `false` and the while loop breaks

```rs
bytes[count + 1] >= 0x41 && bytes[count + 1] <= 0x5A
    || bytes[count + 1] >= 0x61 && bytes[count + 1] <= 0x7A
```

`keyword` doesn't match any of the options so it takes the last branch

```rs
_ => Token::Alpha(bytes[count]),
```

Remember that `bytes[count + 1]` is the space, so `bytes[count]` is `o`.

That newly created `Alpha` token is pushed, `count` is incremented, and a similar thing happens with `world`.

Your test case suggests that you expected this to create several `Alpha` tokens, one for each letter. There's simply nothing in your code that would do this.

However, the question text and the comments in your code suggest you expected this to create a single `Keyword`, referred to as a string. If it did this, it would also fail the test, since it doesn't expect `Keyword`. You would also need to start your input with a `"` character. You can write string literals in rust with `"` characters in a few different ways. These both contain the content `"hello world"`, including quotes:

```rs
"\"hello world\""
r#""hello world""#
```

The first one is escaping quotes, the second is using raw string syntax.

Another discrepancy is that the test case uses ASCII byte literal syntax, but you didn't in the code. I would suggest using ASCII byte literals whenever you are representing text data with bytes.

I agree with the comments that this method of lexing is not ideal. It's not easy to follow what happens to each variable and there's a lot of duplicate code. It'd be useful to learn about some parsing/lexing techniques first.

Comment: thank you that was helpful! my main thing i want to fix right now before i address everything else is how can i push on each byte as an alpha token. because right now im checking to see if there's a keyword match, but if there's not, i push on a single alpha token. instead i want to push on each byte as an alpha token. How can i modify this line "_ => Token::Alpha(bytes[count])," to do so? any help/suggestions would be appreciated!